# Hibernate reverse engineering INTEGER with different sizes

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am working with an existing MySQL database where all INT column types were all set as INT(11).

Using Hibernate, the corresponding generated classes global values are being set as Integer, which will become a problem when a row value has more than 9 digits.

So, I created a reverse engineering file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <type-mapping>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="BIGINT" hibernate-type="Long"></sql-type>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="INTEGER" hibernate-type="Long"
            length="12"></sql-type>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="INTEGER" hibernate-type="Long"
            length="11"></sql-type>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="INTEGER" hibernate-type="Integer"
            length="8"></sql-type>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="INTEGER" hibernate-type="Integer"
            length="9"></sql-type>
        <sql-type jdbc-type="INTEGER" hibernate-type="Long"
            length="10"></sql-type>


        <sql-type jdbc-type="SMALLINT" hibernate-type="Integer"></sql-type>
    </type-mapping>


    <table-filter match-name="DATABASECHANGELOG"
        exclude="true">
    </table-filter>
    <table-filter match-name="DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK"
        exclude="true">
    </table-filter>

</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

The reason I did this, is because that database also has MEDIUMINT and SMALLINT columns and I would like to keep those as Integer since Long is not needed in those cases.

The problem is that the resulting classes are like this:

```xml
INT - Integer (I was expecting Long)
MEDIUMINT - Integer (I know that this Java SQL type doesn't exist that is why I adopted this INTEGER length strategy)
SMALLINT - Integer
```

What it seems is that "length" property is being discarded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi guys. Any comments?